# Exporting font to jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, export

I'm trying to export a font so that you don't have to install the font to run the game
it's working in eclipse but exporting it doesn't work

the folder structure is as following:

```
Project_name
   /src
      -Core(package)
      -game(package)
   /Fonts
      -Origin-Light.ttf
```

I load the font in with following command:

```
font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
                       new FileInputStream("./Fonts/Origin-Light.ttf"));
```

in eclipse it's working just fine, but exporting doesn't seem to load in the font

edit:
Structure in jar file:

```
/core
  - main.class
  - ....
/Fonts
  - Origin-Light.ttf
/game
  - otherclasses.class
/META-INF
  - MANIFEST.MF
/org
  /eclipse
    some more folders
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the fonts folder inside of your source folder, I believe that's the issue:

```
Project_name
  /src
     /Fonts
        -Origin-Light.ttf
     -Core(package)
     -game(package)
```

Resolved in chat, final code:

```
try { 
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 
            trial.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Fonts/Origin-Light.ttf")); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. I couldn't load in the file then.
not even in eclipse

Comment: Did you load it as a resource? see the second part

Comment: And you can't create a font with an Inputstream.

Comment: ^ What? A: That's what your doing already... B: Yeah, you can. You can't create a font with an OutputStream (outputstreams write, inputs read, you can make a font by reading it from a file, not by writing to file)

Comment: Running in eclipse does work again, I see the font in my jar (using winrar on the jar file), but still not working when I run the jar

and I mistyped was ment to be: with THAT inputstream :P

Comment: Are you using the resource code? Also, how does the hierarchy of it look in winrar? (Put that in your question as it wont fit well in comments)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15820/discussion-between-alex-coleman-and-kiwi)

Comment: Instead of using a `FileInputStream`, why not doing this: `font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Login.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Fonts/Origin-Light.ttf"));` ?

Comment: @aymeric Yeah, that's the conclusion we came to. However, it needs to be Fonts/Origin... Not /Fonts/