# Using Font from my JAR

Tags: java, fonts, awt, embedded-resource

I have added a font to my JAR file from eclipse and am trying to use the font within JTextFields.  The setText isn't being drawn when I run the application, just a - in the JTextField.  I based my code off [Exporting font to jar in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131584).

Below is my code:

```
//lets load the font
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Coalition_v2.ttf")); 
font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 14);

txtBrain = new JTextField();
txtBrain.setFont(font);
txtBrain.setText("BRAIN");
txtBrain.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
txtBrain.setEditable(false);
txtBrain.setColumns(10);
txtBrain.setBounds(521, 727, 90, 40);
contentPane.add(txtBrain);
```

I know the font is in the correct place as if I change the .getResourceAsStream to /Coalition_v2.ttf then I get the following error from the console:

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:946)
```

The Font file is contained within
/src/

Output of Jar -tvf as requested:

```
 0 Sun Mar 31 09:51:56 BST 2013 ngd/
     0 Sun Mar 31 09:51:56 BST 2013 ngd/co/
     0 Sun Mar 31 09:51:56 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/
     0 Sun Mar 31 09:51:56 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/
   806 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/About$1.class
   556 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/About$2.class
  4762 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/About.class
  1802 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Help.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$1.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$10.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$11.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$12.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$13.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$14.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$15.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$16.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$17.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$18.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$19.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$2.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$20.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$21.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$22.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$23.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$24.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$25.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$26.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$27.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$28.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$29.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$3.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$30.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$31.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$32.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$33.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$34.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$35.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$36.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$37.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$38.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$39.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$4.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$40.class
  4765 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$41.class
   723 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$42.class
  1185 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$43.class
   697 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$44.class
  1220 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$45.class
   995 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$46.class
   781 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$47.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$5.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$6.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$7.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$8.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$9.class
  2097 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$Field1Listener.class
 47217 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main.class
  1260 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/FileFiltererpdf.class
  1260 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/FileFiltererjpg.class
991552 Wed Jul 27 19:13:00 BST 2011 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Coalition_v2.ttf
991552 Wed Jul 27 19:13:00 BST 2011 Coalition_v2.ttf
409717 Thu Mar 21 14:15:32 GMT 2013 nullpdf.pdf
163009 Thu Mar 21 14:29:08 GMT 2013 Javasplash.jpg
```

The code is being run from Main.class.

EDITED:

Code now looks like this:

```
   Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Coalition_v2.ttf")).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 14); 

System.out.println(font)
```

Sorted.  Thanks for your help, and Andrew for your steer in the right direction.

Comment: *"The Font file is contained within /src/"*  Be more specific & provide the output of `jar -tvf the.jar`  What package is the code in?

Comment: Change `Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Coalition_v2.ttf")` to something more like `this.getClass().getResource("/Coalition_v2.ttf") // note leading '/'` for an URL then print it out to check it is found.

Comment: Closer.  Edited to reflect the update

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
.. Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Coalition_v2.ttf") ..
```

..to something more like..

```
.. this.getClass().getResource("/Coalition_v2.ttf") // note leading '/' ..
```

..for an URL then print it out to check it is found.

The leading `/` means 'look for the root of the class-path' as opposed to from the current package or directory.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in case anyone finds this from google was:

```
  Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Coalition_v2.ttf")).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 14); 

System.out.println(font)
```

Andy

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty strange exception handling in createFont method. If FontFormatException or IOException catched, then it just rethrown. In all other cases will be rethrown:

```
throw new IOException("Problem reading font data.");
```

So your actually issue is even not the IO problem.

First of all take a look at this point. There is such code in this method:

```
final File tFile = AccessController.doPrivileged(
    new PrivilegedExceptionAction<File>() {
        public File run() throws IOException {
            return File.createTempFile("+~JF", ".tmp", null);
        }
    }
);
```

It tries to write into temp directory. You should check if your programm have access to do that.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear in the first post, the error only occurs if I give an invalid path to the font (I.E /fontname), if I leave it with the correct path then I just dont get any text at all with the selected font.