# Cannot get Java Print API to use fonts after exporting to JAR

Tags: java, printing, fonts, awt, embedded-resource

I am writing a Java application with the ability to print formatted views of the data using the Java Printing API. Below is a brief relevant snippet of my code that does the printing:

```
public static void printStaffAssignments(){
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(new StaffAssignmentsPrintable());
    boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();

    if (doPrint) {
        try {
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
           ErrorUtility.createError("Error while trying to print Staff assignments");
        }
    }
}


public static class StaffAssignmentsPrintable implements Printable{

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
            throws PrinterException {

        String[][] data;

        if(page == 0){
            data = FiscalYear.getInstance().getStaffAssignmentsAsStrings();
        }else{
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        final int CHART_TOP = 75;
        int y = CHART_TOP;

        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10));

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            g.drawString(data[i][0], 35, y);
            g.drawString(data[i][1], 135, y);
            g.drawString(data[i][2], 235, y);
            g.drawString(data[i][3], 335, y);
            g.drawString(data[i][4], 435, y);
            y += 17;
        }

                ...

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

}
```

This prints exactly as expected when I run the program out of Eclipse, but when I export it as a JAR, it does not change the font, instead using what I assume to be system default. I tried to use the code in the Java Tutorials (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html) and copied Arial.tff to a folder alongside the JAR, adding in:

```
    try {
         java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
             java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
         ge.registerFont(java.awt.Font.createFont(java.awt.Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new java.io.File("data/Arial.ttf")));
    } 
     ...
```

at a point before any of the print code is called, but still, the JAR will not draw any of the strings using Arial.

The interesting part of it is, I use JLabels in the program itself that are set to the Arial font and, even without the extra GraphicsEnvironment code, the JAR seems to be loading that Arial just fine. For example:

```
Font noStrike = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
...
JLabel name = new JLabel(c.getFullName());
name.setFont(noStrike);
```

Any ideas why my printing code can't find/respect the font?

Comment: Is the font file in your classpath? And does the flow goes to catch block outside eclipse?

Comment: Try running the jar through the command prompt to see what the exception is.I believe it would be a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Have you tried listing names of all fonts in your graphic environment? Does it change between the "exploded" run and run from a jar?

Comment: @Ric Ran it from Terminal. Ran without exception.

Comment: @Olaf The fonts appear to be the same both running out of Eclipse and running as the JAR (I haven't gone line by line, but both seem to find all the fonts that I'm utilizing in the program)

Comment: Are you catching Exception or a specific custom exception ?

Comment: @Ric In the actual printing part, I'm only catching PrinterException. In the section where I register my fonts, I catch FontFormatException and IOException. If a PrintException is thrown in the try/catch, it will open up a Dialog. If the FontFormat or IO exceptions are thrown, it prints a stack trace.

Comment: So try catching FileNotFoundException or just Exception where you are registering the fonts to see where you are going wrong. Once you get the problem you can remove these.

Comment: @Ric I added in a catch for general Exception. Still nothing thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131584/exporting-font-to-jar-in-eclpise) answer. I cannot explain why this would only be affecting the Printing API and not the Swing components, but in order to use the font in the Printing API, I had to include it under the `/src` folder and use the `getResourceAsStream()` method to access it.

It seems as though, at least in my case, while Swing was able to access the system fonts and external font files, the Printing API or Graphics2D required that the files be loaded as an InputStream.